# How to protect floor carpet while using office chair?

Tags: home, office-supplies, furniture, office, carpet

I installed new carpet and trying to protect it from few office chairs with wheels (in home office setting). Carpet is medium fleck thick. I checked carpet protectors for office chairs, but this solution is expensive for me. Can anyone suggest cheaper way of protecting carpet while using office chairs so that chair can move easily and carpet is also protected.

Comment: Do the chairs have castors?  The answers would be different.

Comment: @Chenmunka yes, the chairs are with castors.

Answer (score 2):

A certain Scandinavian home goods store sells 100x120cm rigid plastic (PET) floor protectors for €25, which work very well and should be within budget if they're in your area or deliver there, but any plate material that's both rigid and wide enough for chair movements will do.

If you don't have access to the above, you could use a piece of more universally available MDF (which price wise is quite close per m2), triplex will probably also do (although this might be noisier and damage/crack more easily over time). As the drop at the ridge is a lot higher compared to the floor protector above, and your chair might get stuck when it rolls over, you might want to increase the size to, say, 150x200cm, so this doesn't happen. Continuous plate material is strongly preferred for this, any seams would (eventually) be noticeable when you roll over them.

Another  alternative is cutting out a part of the carpet where the wheelchair will be (you can keep it in storage and reinsert later), although this depends on what's underneath it. Some carpet substrates are not well suited for point pressure.

Answer (score 0):

**Merrily, We Roll Along Carpet Hack:**

To protect the carpet, use the largest diameter, softest, and widest rollers that your chair can accommodate to spread the load over as much rug area as possible. A five-roller base is preferable to a four-roller one.

This rug-friendly equipped base will take more effort to move around on the rug than any other rollers/casters.

The easiest chairs to move around on the rug will be those with large diameter, hard, roller-blade style casters. The thinner profile of the roller-blade will have less contact area and exert greater pressure on the carpet, which will crush the glued base and underlay fabric of the carpet. The mechanical action will lessen the life of the carpet.

Good Luck.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for above answers. I solved the problem putting pieces of carpet underneath the caster chair : I got 12 x 2 feet carpet piece from nearby home improvement store at rate of $0.94/sq feet, cut that big piece into 3 smaller pieces using a utility knife ($5-6 in the same home improvement store), and put the 3 cut pieces under chairs. The carpet pieces on top of floor carpet may not look very pretty, but I found it is economical way to protect floor carpet beneath and chair rolls fairly easily.